# How to get Spock annotation closure result

Tags: spock, geb

I am wondering how I can obtain the boolean value of an IgnoreIf spock annotation.

For example in my script I may have something like this:

```
@IgnoreIf({someBooleanMethod()})
def "Some Feature Method"(){
    // code and stuff
}
```

I also have a custom spock extension. In that extention I have this:

```
//iterates over each feature method in a spec
for (FeatureInfo feature : spec.getFeatures()){
    if(feature.getFeatureMethod().reflection.isAnnotationPresent(IgnoreIf.class)&&feature.getFeatureMethod().reflection.getAnnotation(IgnoreIf.class).value()){
        //some more code goes here
    }
}
```

I want to evaluate the IgnoreIf closure for each feature method that contains a IgnoreIf closure. If I am not mistaken, `feature.getFeatureMethod().reflection.getAnnotation(IgnoreIf.class).value()` should give me the clouse from the given annotation, but I do not know how to actually evaluate the `someBooleanMethod` I have inside of the closure to see if it is true or false. How do I do that?

Comment: Just look at the code of the Extension org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.IgnoreIfExtension

Comment: @Leonard Brünings I assume you are referring to the `evaluateCondition` method found in that class. It is a non static method, so how to obtain an instance of that object so that I may call that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new IgnoreIfExtension().visitFeatureAnnotation(feature.getFeatureMethod().reflection.getAnnotation(IgnoreIf.class), feature)`

This is what I did. if the IgnoreIf condition is true it will set it to skipped on its own